# Saving an image in an html document using Agillity pack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to save images in a jpeg (or any format) for a given page.

Say that I have this node in the document:

```
<td class="leftCol" align="center">
          <img src="/Images/LoadImage/1122334455" id="bp250_bp250_bp250_main_sub_sub_itemImage" alt="Object #1" style="border:none;" />

                    <div class="variations">
                        &nbsp;

                    </div>
                    <div class="rotate">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="lightbox" onclick="return RotateCardImage(event, this, true);">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
```

I want to save the image contained in the

```
HtmlNodeCollection allImgNodes = docToParse.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
```

and then this:

```
foreach(var allImgNode in allImgNodes)
{
    if(allImgNode.Attributes["alt] != null)
    {
        if(allImgNode.Attributes["alt"].Value == objName)
        {
            (... and here I am...)
        }
    }
}
```

The objName is a string that correspond to the name of the object, in this example, "Object #1" would be objName.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Darin (here: [C# htmlagility pack , save image from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398566/c-sharp-htmlagility-pack-save-image-from-a-url)), I understood another method that helped me a lot.

First with Html Agility Pack I got the url of the image which I stored like this:

```
string fileName = directoryToStoreImgs + objName + ".jpeg";
```

Then I used a webClient to download the image:

```
using (var imgClient = new WebClient())
{
    imgClient.DownloadFile(objUrl, fileName);
}
```

And now I can store my images :)